# Is this a wise use of a global variable with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Python's multiprocessing library to send a bunch of data to an API. I have to send one record per request, so I'm using pooling to make n parallel requests. I'd like to take results from those requests (summarized into a string) and combine it with other data for logging.

So here is a simplified example of what I'm trying, distilled down to the multiprocessing itself. Is it wise to use a global variable like this? Is there a better way?

Thanks

```
import multiprocessing

message = ""

def cTest(m):
    global message
    message = "-".join(m)

def mTest(name):
    print(name)
    return("t" + name)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    testList = ['Jake', 'Jake', 'Jake', 'Jill', 'Jake', 'Jake']

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map_async(mTest, testList, 1, cTest)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("-->" + message)
```

Output

```
Jake
Jake
Jake
Jill
JakeJake

-->tJake-tJake-tJake-tJill-tJake-tJake
```

Comment: Does your code work? What output do you get? If there’s an error message edit the full text of the error into your question __as text__

Comment: It does appear to work, but I'm not sure if this is correct usage.

Comment: In almost any OOP language `globals` are a bad idea. It violates the entire idea of encapsulation but for the most part it's fine. It's typically better to pass some context to a method which would return a new context that updates the old context. so `message=cTest(m,message)`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter perhaps you can provide an answer with your approach so it’s clearer? BenW don’t see how you can avoid a global if using a callback to a function, although perhaps you can provide for the callback a method on a class instance that updates an attribute on the instance, so avoiding the global.

Comment: you dont't need global variable because you can get  results using `results = pool.map_async(...).get()`

Comment: on some systems processes don't share variables (even global) and global variable may not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this without `cTemp` and `global`

```
results = pool.map_async(...)

values = results.get()

message = "-".join(values)

print("-->" + message)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code

```
import multiprocessing

def mTest(name):
    return "t" + name

if __name__ == '__main__':

    testList = ['Jake', 'Jake', 'Jake', 'Jill', 'Jake', 'Jake']

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)

    results = pool.map_async((mTest, testList, 1)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    
    values = results.get()
    message = "-".join(values)

    print("-->" + message)
```